# Problem when reading a small number as a LaTeX input

Tags: latex, input, evaluation

I've got a String variable defined as `b="4.0 \cdot 10^{-5}"`, which is clearly written as LaTeX input.

The problem is that when I want to obtain the expression from it using `c=ToExpression[b,TeXForm]`, I get the following output:

`4.\[CenterDot]1/100000`.

To avoid that problem, I tried first doing `b=StringReplace[b," \cdot " -> "*"]` but, if I do that, then the output of the other line of code gets senseless:

`9.76563*10^(-9)`

Is there another way to deal with this problem with `\cdot`?

Comment: It's a matter of precedence. TeXForm is interpreting the input as `(4.0*10)^{-5}`.

Comment: `Is there another way to deal with this problem with \cdot?` it is better to go back to the source to fix the problem there. What sympy expression did you have that generated `\cdot` as its Latex translation?

Comment: The number was 4e-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not really use `*` in Latex. No one does. This is simply bad latex.    How did you generate "4.0 * 10^{-5}" as latex to start with?

Try `b = "$4.0 \\times 10^{-5}$"` which when compiled in Latex, gives
$$
4.0 \times 10^{-5}
$$

Then now `b = ToExpression[b, TeXForm]` gives `0.00004`  But if you want to keep the form without evaluation, then you can use

```
b = ToExpression[b, TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh you are right! I already made some changes actually. I will give all the information about how did I get that variable actually. Maybe there is another way to solve the problem in a straightforward way.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you have any suggestion? `\times` is not working for me. If I replace `\cdot` by `\times`, the `\t` gets understood as a tabulation by Mathematica.

Comment: @edgardeitor Use `\\times` instead of `\times`.

Comment: Yes it should be `\\times`. bad typing on my part. Any latex command in string should be escaped.

Comment: That works perfect!

Comment: No worries. Thank you so much to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, but `ToExpression["4.0 * 10^{-5}"]` works fine. So does `ToExpression["4.0 \, 10^{-5}", TeXForm]`. Here's what's happening:

```
Trace@ToExpression["4.0 * 10^{-5}", TeXForm]
(* {ToExpression[4.0 * 10^{-5},TeXForm],1/(4. 10)^5,{4. 10,40.},1/40.^5,9.76563*10^-9} *)
```